# how to create textboxes and buttons inside a view?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I m doing a Eclipse plug-in project to develop an IDE. I want to create a view with a text box and a button inside it. I know to create a view, it can be created using the Eclipse plug-in `org.eclipse.ui.views`, but I'm not able to create the textbox and the button inside it.

Can anyone help me in doing this please?

Comment: Where exactly are you planning to show this textbox? Is it swings or something you are talking about?

Comment: in that view,the user can come and enter some text and once he presses the search button,my ide should search a file,return the matched text back to the view.It is not using the swings.it should be done using eclipse plug-in development

Comment: the textbox should be shown in the left side of the window,in a separate view,as a search view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every view is a class which implements `IViewPart`. It has a method `public void createPartControl(Composite parent)`. That's where you create your controls, using SWT. If you don't know SWT, read [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/SWT/article.html).